# Missing Authentication Token while accessing API Gateway when tested in chrome but working in postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker

I created an AWS Lambda function which invokes the endpoint of ML model I created in sagemaker. I tested it and it's working fine. Next I created REST API that calls this lambda function. I  set any authentication type as NONE. Anyone with the url can access it. I created it following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/)  aws blog. I tested my url in postman. It's working fine in postman but when I entered the url in chrome, its throwing `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}` error. Can someone please tell how do I get rid of that error while testing my url in chrome

Comment: Kindly post your POSTMAN request, also are you attaching token with your request?

Comment: it's got absolutely nothing to do with the token.

Answer (score 3):

The error is misleading. It's got absolutely nothing to do with tokens. What is *actually* happening is that the URL you are trying to access is invalid.

API Gateway's URL looks like this: https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.some-region.amazonaws.com/your-stage but it's very likely that you created an endpoint on API Gateway, which would then be accessible via https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.some-region.amazonaws.com/your-stage/YOUR_ENDPOINT

If you hit the base URL or a path which does not exist, you will get that weird, misleading `Missing Authentication Token` message.

So, long story short, hit a valid path for your API and it should work just fine.

Tip: maybe you are doing a POST request via Postman but whenever you try with the browser it issues a GET request, which would also result in an invalid path and therefore the `Missing Authentication Token` message.

Comment: I'm doing a POST request on Postman. How do I make my browser to issue the same POST request? Also my API gateway looks like  https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.some-region.amazonaws.com/your-stage/my_resource_created_in_APIGateway

Comment: You don't. Not from the address bar at least. You have to create some frontend code to actually issue the POST request with a JSON content.  For example: https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/ however, I think you are putting the cart before the horse given the fact you don't understand the basics of the HTTP protocol and how GET/POST requests are different from each other. I suggest you go over these steps first.